# k times Fold with 3 changing extra variables

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to generate a folded function like follows:

```
  f[ a[[3]], b[[3]], c[[3]], 
     f[ a[[2]], b[[2]], c[[2]], 
        f[ a[[1], b[[1]], c[[1]], 
           fstart
        ]
     ]
  ]
```

But instead of 3 times folded, I need it k-times folded.

`a`,`b`,`c` are lists containing numbers.

I tried to play around with `Fold` and `FoldList` and searched for similar questions, but I couldn't make it work :/.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does it fit your needs?

```
aa = Array[a, 5];
bb = Array[b, 5];
cc = Array[c, 5];

Fold[f[Sequence @@ #2, #] &, fstart, Transpose@{aa, bb, cc}]
```

> ```
>    f[ 
>      a[5], b[5], c[5], 
>      f[ a[4], b[4], c[4], 
>         f[ a[3], b[3], c[3], 
>            f[ a[2], b[2], c[2], 
>               f[ a[1], b[1], c[1], 
>                  fstart
>               ]
>             ]
>          ]
>       ]
>     ]
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can use `Indexed` and `Fold` over the indices:

```
Fold[
  f[Indexed[a, #2], Indexed[b, #2], Indexed[c, #2], #1] &,
  start, 
  Range[4]
]

Out[] = f[Indexed[a, {4}], Indexed[b, {4}], Indexed[c, {4}], 
 f[Indexed[a, {3}], Indexed[b, {3}], Indexed[c, {3}], 
  f[Indexed[a, {2}], Indexed[b, {2}], Indexed[c, {2}], 
   f[Indexed[a, {1}], Indexed[b, {1}], Indexed[c, {1}], start]]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
abc = {a, b, c};
k = 5;

Fold[f[## & @@ Through@abc@#2, #] &, fstart, Range @ k]
```

> `f[a[5], b[5], c[5],
>   f[a[4], b[4], c[4],
>     f[a[3], b[3], c[3],
>       f[a[2], b[2], c[2],
>         f[a[1], b[1], c[1],
>           fstart]]]]]`

Make it a function with 4 arguments:

```
ClearAll[fOLD]
fOLD[f_, lst_, strt_, k_] := Fold[f[## & @@ Through@lst@#2, #] &, strt, Range@k];
```

***Examples:***

```
fOLD[f, {a, b, c}, fstart, 5]
```

> same result

```
fOLD[g, {x, y, z, w}, u0, 3]
```

> `g[x[3], y[3], z[3], w[3], 
>     g[x[2], y[2], z[2], w[2], 
>       g[x[1], y[1], z[1], w[1], 
>         u0]]]`